# Lambda Expressions Arrays.sort

Tags: java, sorting, lambda

I have a question regarding Arrays.sort in Java and how this works with a lambda expression.

```
Arrays.sort(logs, (log1, log2) -> { 
   ... either returns -1, 0, 1
}
```

Could anyone explain to me how this lambda expression exactly works with respect to the return values?

If more information is needed, let me know.

Edit: I have a very base understanding on Comparators and if you would like to explain that as well, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You basically need to understand, how does a `Comparator` work. The sorting API in the question expects two inputs, one the array to be sorted and another the comparator to be used for comparing the elements to decide their order. The [JavaDoc for Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) should be a good place to start with.

Comment: @Naman Care to explain?

Comment: @Naman I understand that much, but why are there a tuple of values? I get with sorting for example by numbers, i.e. a.number - b.number -> greater number is given a higher index value in the order, but with the tuple if for example two logs are given a value of 1, is a merge sort occuring to determine their order after?

Comment: @Naman I think I might have just answered the question. If a merge sort occurs, all values will be compared against one another and a log with a value of 1 in one sort, can have a value of 0 or -1 in an another sort.

Comment: That isn't a tuple; it's the param list for the lambda function. The sort method will call your lambda repeatedly for different pairs of values (as necessary) until the entire array is sorted. (Edit: you got it!)

Comment: @AjahnCharles tuple was the wrong word. I was thinking of triplet lol. But thank ya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Comparator` is an object that answers the question of how pairs of objects of suitable type compare to each other with respect to a given ordering.  Its `compare()` method accepts two arguments, and reports on their relative order by returning -1 if the first argument is ordered before the second, +1 if the first is ordered after the second, or 0 if the two are equal, with respect to the ordering implemented.

That can be used in various ways, but in particular, it can be used to sort a sequence of such objects, with the `Comparator` used in place of the relational operators (`<`, `>`, ...), which do not apply to most types of objects.  Moreover, `Comparator`s allow objects to be sorted according to any chosen order, as for all practical intents and purposes the chosen `Comparator` implementation *defines* the order.  This is how `Arrays.sort()` uses `Comparators` -- the `Comparator` provided serves as a stand-in for relational operators.

Because `Comparator` is a functional interface, implementations can be provided in the form of lambdas.  There is nothing new or different about using a lambda with `Arrays.sort()`.  It is simply the form of `Arrays.sort()` that relies on a `Comparator` to define the order, with that `Comparator` implemented via a lambda.

Comment: First, thank you for the detailed explanation, I really appreciate the help. I am getting to understand comparators better now (The documentation doesn't really paint a picture for me as a visual learner since it doesn't really go into the in depth workings of it imo) As another question, then when I have been using Arrays.sort(integer array) there has been a predefined comparator that has been sorting my integer array..? (Edit: Seems that is the case. With a lambda expression, you have more flexibility in defining the ordering you specifically want i.e. it isnt ascending)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRX6qO46l44 This video so far seems pretty good to anyone who needs a better understanding.

Comment: @J.Doe, the version of `Arrays.sort()` that accepts an `int[]` is tuned for sorting `int`s.  It uses the relational operators rather than a comparator.  On the other hand, if you pass an `Integer[]` or an array of any other reference type that implements `Comparable`, it is substantially equivalent to using a `Comparator` obtained via `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.

Comment: That is cool.. So they recognize whether it is a primitive type or not and then deduce whether to use a relational operator or comparable and then on top of that give you the flexibility to implement your own way of ordering. Smart!

Comment: One more question. Is there a rule to switch the ordering of -1 and 1. For example, o1.compareTo(o2) vs o2.compareTo(o1) where the former gives ascending and the latter gives descending? In the former, negative values are positioned leftward, and in the latter negative values are positioned rightward?

Comment: @J.Doe, to sort in a different order, you provide a different `Comparator`, one that yields the ordering you want.  For the specific case of the reverse order of a `Comparator` you already have, you can use that `Comparator`'s `reversed()` method to obtain the new `Comparator`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this will use your lambda expression as a Comparator.

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
>   In the foregoing description, the notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function, which is defined to return one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.

For more information please read the docs.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html